# Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment: 'CommandText'

Tags: sql, parameters, adodb, command-text

I have the following code in a Classic ASP website that I have to update the SQL statements and for some reason I keep getting the error Wrong number of argument or invalid property assignment 'Command Text.  I have tried changing the createParameter to the first line of code but that does not work.  So I changed it to the line in the second CreateParameter but neither one works.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@parm1",adSingle,adParamInput,,tailno)  


set cmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
cmd.ActiveConnection = tadsdb
cmd.CommandText "INSERT INTO TAR_DATA (TN_ID) VALUES (?)"
cmd.CommandType = adCmdText
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@parm1",3,1,,tailno)
cmd.Execute
```

Comment: You are missing the assignment sign between your query and CommandText. Have you tried changing it to the following?

`cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO TAR_DATA (TN_ID) VALUES (?)"`

Comment: Thank I looked at that code for a long time and never saw it.

Comment: I will repost my answer so that you could accept my answer and close your question, happy to hear this resolved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

`cmd.CommandText` doesn't take an argument but requires an assignment.

To resolve your problem you should add the '=' operator between the CommandText and your given query.

This line:

`cmd.CommandText "INSERT INTO TAR_DATA (TN_ID) VALUES (?)"`

Should become:

`cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO TAR_DATA (TN_ID) VALUES (?)"`